# Running Regression Test Selection (RTS) for Scala (SBT) - Ekstazi/STARTS

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

Has anyone tried RTS tools like Ekstazi or STARTS to perform Regression test selection (RTS) for scala SBT (not maven) projects where tests are written using ScalaTests?

I tried by adding following library dependencies in build.sbt but it seems like RTS is not performed when I ran unit test cases (using **sbt test** command):

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ekstazi/org.ekstazi.core/5.3.0
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ekstazi/org.ekstazi.scalatest/5.3.0

Can someone please tell me what is the correct way?